# Is the absolute value function an equivalence relation?

Tags: proof-writing, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the well-known absolute value function: $f(x) = \lvert x \rvert$. Show that f, considered as a
relation, is neither reflexive nor symmetric. Show also that it is transitive.

I'm not sure how to proceed on this one. Is the absolute value function not an equivalence relation?

Comment: By the way, the only function that, considered as a relation, is an equivalence relation is the identity function.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen is right, but I wonder if you had in mind something like what Wikipedia calls [the equivalence kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Equivalence_kernel) of the absolute value function. That would be a different relation $S$ where $xSy\iff |x|=|y|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relation is defined by

$$(\forall x,y\in\Bbb R)\; (x \mathcal R y\iff y=|x|)$$

So, it is not reflexive since
$-1$ is not in relation with $ -1 $ because $|-1|\ne -1$.

It is not symetric since
$-1 $ is in relation with $ 1$ but $ 1 $ is not.

It is transitive :

$$x\mathcal Ry \quad \text{ and } \quad y\mathcal R z\implies$$
$$|x|=y \quad \text{ and } \quad|y|=z \implies |x|=|y|=z$$

$$\implies x \mathcal R z$$